# Python negative regex for hours

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a negative regex in python with the module re (and findall) to capture a part of a string

My Input String :

```
"10:00a.m or 4:00 p.m"
```

(My regex is quite complicated because I needed a difference between 10:00:00 and 10:00)
So, I have tried this regex:

```
'(?<!:)\b(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{1,2})\b(?!\s*:)\s*([.]?(a|p)\s*‌​[.]?\s*m[.]?)?'
```

But if there isn't a whitespace between the number and the a (or p) it's not working, I think it's because of the \b but I don't see why.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/1gYgFh/33

Comment: Not working here : https://regex101.com/r/1gYgFh/34

Answer (score 0):

Look on this regex:

```
r'(\d+:\d+.*[ap][.]m).{1,}?(\d+:\d+.*[ap][.]m)'
```

[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/1gYgFh/25)